# Webstorm 11 check typescript files without compiling. Using webpack for compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, webpack

i'm trying to use webstorm with webpack and typescript and i have stuck with errors checking.
I want to compile ts files with webpack, so i need to avoid  compiling source files via Webstorm, but it seems like Webstorm perform error checking only during compilation process.

Corresponding to webstorm docs "Resolve objects using tsconfig.json" should activate Errors checking without compilation, but is doesnt.

example code, which Webstorm doesnt highlight

```
 { let z = 4;}
 console.log(z);
```

my tsconfig file:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "out": "build/tsc.js",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In same time  Visual studio code display errors fine.
Do i have any errors in my configs ?
Is it possible to highlight errors correct with Webstorm or other JetBrains IDE?

Typescript version 1.7, Webstorm 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Original Answer (outdated - see UPDATE below):**

As Valery correctly pointed out you can set the "noEmit" property to true to prevent the compiler creating any output files.

However, if your Webpack setup uses the same tsconfig.json file it will also prevent webpack from creating the output files. You'll only notice this the next time webpack is restarted.

In my webpack setup I'm using the "ts-loader" Typescript loader.
As mentioned on the [ts-loader github page](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) you can override compiler options.

So this is my setup:

**tsconfig.json (used by IDE and Webpack)**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true, // do not emit js and map files
    ...
```

**webpack.config.json (used by Webpack)**

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    query: {
      'compilerOptions': {
        "noEmit": false // make sure js files do get emitted
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

Et voila: IDE compiler checks without js and js.map files polluting your source code folder!

***UPDATE:*** My answer was a valid workaround in January but today the better solution is to use the Typescript service inside Webstorm/IDEA as suggested by anstarovoyt.

Also don't forget to UNcheck "Enable TypeScript Compiler" as shown here:

[image]

Comment: This got rid of the annoying `unresolved function or method require` error in webstorm.  YES!

Answer (score 5):

WebStorm 2016.1 (and other IJ 2016.1 IDEs) supports `"compileOnSave"` option. Example:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

**Update:** WebStorm 2016.2 has the new 'TypeScript service' integration. 
You don't need the 'TypeScript complier' integration at all. Just check the option 'Use TypeScript service'. Moreover the new integration works much more faster.

**Update 2:** The integration is enabled by default in WebStorm 2016.3

[image: Option 'Use TypeScript service']

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to prevent compiler output vis tsconfig - noEmit option.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

With this config i have no extra file and correct error highlight in webstorm.

Comment: webpack ts compiler uses the same config, but override this setting in the webpack config is too much to use webstorm

Answer (score 0):

In your Webpack configuration file add this in `module.rules`:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    noEmit: false,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

Obviously, if you already have a rule for `test: /\.tsx?$/`, you should combine it with the above.

And note that `module.rules` is an array of objects, not an object.